# Apache httpd2.4: flush mod_cache_disk without restarting the server

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpd.conf, http-caching

I am caching the static content of my high load dynamic website using httpd 2.4 disk cache. I am using httpd2.4 as proxy server. Back-end server is Apache Tomcat8. My cache configuration is like :

```
<IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>
  CacheEnable disk /css
  CacheEnable disk /images
  CacheEnable disk /fonts
  CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie X-Auth-Token
  CacheRoot /var/cache/httpd/proxy
</IfModule>

CustomLog "logs/cached-requests.log" common env=cache-hit
CustomLog "logs/uncached-requests.log" common env=cache-miss
CustomLog "logs/revalidated-requests.log" common env=cache-revalidate
CustomLog "logs/invalidated-requests.log" common env=cache-invalidate
```

I am planning to cache the javascripts also. But these files i need to update frequently. 
So, the question is how do I flush the cache (or refresh particular urls) without restarting the server and without interrupting the user experience(i mean no down time). Any suggestion is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: For intelligent caching you can use `mod_expires` module and set expiration time by file type. For example: `<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>`

Comment: thank you. but what to do for realtime update

Comment: I am curious to know why your JavaScript resources be changing in real time. My be I am missing something.

Comment: Does httpd restart refresh the cache?

Comment: Memory cache: probably yes. Disk cache: No

Comment: thank you. please let me know if i want to refresh the disk cache on server restart how to achieve that?

Comment: Although [htcaheclean](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htcacheclean.html) is the one to do it manually. But I don't think/don't know how you automate that with a trigger of restart on apache without too much hassle.